# manager.queryUsageStats returning an empty list in a service

Tags: android, service, usagestatsmanager

I have a 1x1 pixel service.  I have set it up to catch touch events outside of the application.
When I capture a touch event, I want to be able to get a list of the Activities.  So...
touchEvent triggers a check to make sure I have permissions, then, it runs a method attempting to create a list of UsageStats.
The Log "No Stats (NOT NULL)..." is always hit.  Even if I open another app, and click on it's screen.  I register the touch event in my service but I don't get a list of UsageStats

Any help would be apprciated.

```
@TargetApi(22)
    private boolean hasPermission() {
        AppOpsManager appOps = (AppOpsManager)
                getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
        int mode = appOps.checkOpNoThrow(AppOpsManager.OPSTR_GET_USAGE_STATS,
                android.os.Process.myUid(), getPackageName());
        if(mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED)
            Log.i(TAG, "Permmissions ... GOOD");
        else
            Log.i(TAG, "Permissions... BAD");
        return mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED;
    }


@TargetApi(22)
    private void retrieveUsageStats(){
        Log.i(TAG, "Inside retrieveUsageStats... ");
        UsageStatsManager manager = (UsageStatsManager) getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
        List<UsageStats> stats = manager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_YEARLY,
                2016, 2018);
        if(stats != null && stats.size() >= 1)
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "Package Name " + stats.get(0).getPackageName());
        }
        else if(stats == null)
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "No Stats (NULL)...");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "No Stats (NOT NULL)...");
        }
    }
```